# Creating directory inside USB device on Windows

Tags: python-3.x, usb

What I need to do is creating directory inside USB device via running Backup.exe(Backup.py) inside USB device.

I mean when  Backup.exe  execute  from the USB device, backup.exe detect USB device and create Backup folder on USB device.

I’m hardcoding USB device  and dir_path

```
if "Removable Disk" in disk.Description or "My Passport" == disk.VolumeName:
dir_path = r'I:\\'
```

Is there better way to do automatically without hardcoding disk.Description  and dir_path?

```
#pip install WMI
import wmi
import os


letter = wmi.WMI()

def disk_info():
     for disk in letter.Win32_LogicalDisk():
          if "Removable Disk" in disk.Description or "My Passport" == disk.VolumeName:
              print("="*20, "USB Letter Information", "="*20)
              Description = disk.Description
              DeviceID = disk.DeviceID
              VolumeName = disk.VolumeName
              return  Description, DeviceID,VolumeName  
              break
    

info = disk_info()
print(info)

dir_name = ("Backup")
#dir_path = 
dir_path = r'I:\\'
file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, dir_name)

if not os.path.exists(file_path):
   os.makedirs(file_path)
   print("Folder created in ==>", info)
```

The output:

```
==================== USB Letter Information ====================
('Removable Disk', 'I:', 'KINGSTON')
Folder created in ==> ('Removable Disk', 'I:', 'KINGSTON')
>>>
```

Update1:

I have updated scripted, and it shows information about USB flash drive and the path to USB but still does not create a folder in USB and I get this error message.

```
import os
import wmi

letter = wmi.WMI()

def disk_info():
     for disk in letter.Win32_LogicalDisk():
          if "Removable Disk" in disk.Description or "My Passport" == disk.VolumeName:
              print("="*20, "USB Letter Information", "="*20)
              Description = disk.Description
              DeviceID = disk.DeviceID
              VolumeName = disk.VolumeName
              return  Description, DeviceID,VolumeName  
              break
    
info = disk_info()
print(info)


def device_id():
     for disk in letter.Win32_DiskDrive():
         if "USB" in disk.InterfaceType:
             DeviceID = disk.DeviceID 
             return DeviceID 
     
dev_id = device_id()
print(dev_id)


dir_name = ("Backup")
dir_path = dev_id 
#dir_path = r'I:\\'
file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, dir_name)

if not os.path.exists(file_path):
   os.makedirs(file_path)
   print("Folder created in ==>", dev_id )
```

The output:

```
==================== USB Letter Information ====================
('Removable Disk', 'I:', 'ESD-USB')
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2
Traceback (most recent call last):

  mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [WinError 31] A device attached to the system is not functioning: '\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE2\\
```

Comment: From reading your code and output, the drive letter is in `disk.DeviceID`, and in the code you've posted that would be `I:`.

Comment: @KenWhite Yes, because I have hardcoded driver letter as you see in dir_path which does not work with other usb and computer

Comment: `dir_path` is not used in your `disk_info` function at all, and neither is `dir_name`, so I don't see how it can have anything to do with it.

Comment: Neither is `file_path`, which is the combined`dir_path` and `dir_name`. In fact, `disk_info` is called before they're ever declared or have values assigned to them.

Comment: @KenWhite Ok, how can I use dir_path in my disk_info? I'm pretty new to python

Comment: That makes no sense. Your whole point is that you don't want to  use a hard-coded path, and when I  point out that you're not using one now, suddenly you want to know how to do so? Make up your mind - what is the actual question you're asking, and what is it you're trying to do?

Comment: Backup.exe in my USB driver when start running should detect automatically USB driver letter and create Backup directory inside the USB drive.

Comment: And you can do that by writing a function that does the same thing as `disk_info`, but returns `DeviceID`, which will give you the drive letter (as I pointed out in my very first comment).